# Running a graphical app in a Docker container, on a remote server with ssh

Tags: docker, authentication, ssh, x11, x11-forwarding

I am trying to connect via `ssh -X` to a remote machine and from them run a docker with the graphical interface enabled.

I have found and tried to follow this tutorial:
https://blog.yadutaf.fr/2017/09/10/running-a-graphical-app-in-a-docker-container-on-a-remote-server/

but I am getting the following error even with the final script

> `xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :10`

if I add a `sudo chmod -R 777 display` in the script I get this error instead:

> `X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
>   xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: :10`

What I am missing? There is anything else I should configure either locally, on the remote machine or the container?

#### on local machine

```
$ xauth list
test/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f3e4afd36654c52965e3e529c8a3ce88
test/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a806b599d75e8b6df4f107a87faa952f
test/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  85342ce3b19106adfea27f3333ba19d8
test/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  224cda4faa7c6d128748c2c35387df68
test:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5061d4d95dc44d11b60137ad215f1abe
test:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1eddbb0db43952186265eca6e49e08a4

$ echo $DISPLAY
:0.0
```

#### on remote machine (`ssh -X localhost`)

```
$ xauth list
test/unix:1  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  f3e4afd36654c52965e3e529c8a3ce88
test/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  a806b599d75e8b6df4f107a87faa952f
test/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  85342ce3b19106adfea27f3333ba19d8
test/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  224cda4faa7c6d128748c2c35387df68
test:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  5061d4d95dc44d11b60137ad215f1abe
test:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  1eddbb0db43952186265eca6e49e08a4

$ echo $DISPLAY
test:10.0

$ sudo lsof -i4:6010
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
sshd    25693    me  10u   IPv4 575887      0t0  TCP *:6010 (LISTEN)
sshd    25693    me  13u   IPv4 583043      0t0  TCP localhost:6010->localhost:33366 (ESTABLISHED)
socat   25735    me   3u   IPv4 585843      0t0  TCP localhost:33366->localhost:6010 (ESTABLISHED)
```

#### within container

```
$ xauth list
xterm/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  85342ce3b19106adfea27f3333ba19d8

$ echo $DISPLAY
:10
```

p.s. I also have tried without success the following SO solutions [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429394/x11-forwarding-of-a-gui-app-running-in-docker), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235040/run-x-application-in-a-docker-container-reliably-on-a-server-connected-via-ssh-w)