# Java GUI Maven Project in Docker with X11 Error

Tags: java, maven, docker, x11

I have a JavaFX Maven Project. Run I run the Jar file, a GUI pops open for the user. I am trying to run it from a Docker container. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

I keep getting this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException:  No
>   X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation
>   which requires it.

Here is my Docker file (using a solution from [here](https://blog.rabin.io/linux/running-java-gui-application-in-docker)).

```
FROM docker.io/java as firstStage
WORKDIR /workdir/
RUN /usr/sbin/useradd --comment Developer \
                  --home-dir /home/developer \
                  --non-unique --uid 1000 --user-group --system \
                  --shell /bin/bash developer && mkdir -p /home/developer

RUN chown -R developer:developer /home/developer && mkdir -p /opt/app && chown -R developer:developer /opt/app

RUN echo 'developer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
USER developer
ENV HOME /home/developer
VOLUME /opt/app

FROM maven:3.5.0-jdk-8
COPY --from=firstStage /workdir/ .
COPY . /
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openjfx && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && mvn clean install && DISPLAY=localhost:0.0

CMD ["java","-jar","/target/CodeDemo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I've looked through plenty of other answers to this question, and here is what else I've tried:
Running CMD with `-Djava.awt.headless=true`.
Trying the SO solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429394/x11-forwarding-of-a-gui-app-running-in-docker) where you run "xauth add" within the container. But xauth "is not found". So I tried adding `RUN sudo apt-get install xauth` to the Dockerfile. When I tried to build, I got an error saying xauth wasn't found. I did the same thing with `x11-apps`.

I thought maybe it wouldn't install because it couldn't be found on my host machine (just a random guess), but I can run xauth on my host machine.

The only other solutions I've seen involved Putty and ssh. I just want to run the Docker container on my computer, not ssh into another one. I also saw some answers about virtualization. Do I have to create a whole virtual machine to run one program? Or am I missing something?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Some inspiration maybe: read [this](http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/)

Comment: This seems a great challenge, not sure if you could run desktop GUI applications without virtualizing the whole target OS. Good luck and let us know.

Comment: Thank you both. I was thinking this may not be as straightforward as I thought, but I just got started with Docker and thought I was missing something simple.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks for that article.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible. The given error message is actually quite good.
**You need to set X11 DISPLAY variable.**

The solution to your problem could be as simple as adding

```
-e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
```

to your `docker run` command. You might need to run

```
sudo xhost +
```

before that, in order to allow connections to your host XServer.

You can also have a look at the following blog posts, who explain this in more detail:

- https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110
- https://medium.com/dot-debug/running-chrome-in-a-docker-container-a55e7f4da4a8

If you also need actual graphics support, for e.g. OpenGL, have a look at https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker.