# Docker cannot connect to X server

Tags: docker, xserver

I have created a docker image for opencv and facial reckognition to simplify the setup process.

But the recognize.py script needs X Server to show the image result. Here is what I have done so far:

```
sudo docker run -t -d --name opencv opencv:latest
sudo docker exec -it opencv bash /extract-embeddings.sh
sudo docker exec -it opencv bash /train-model.sh
```

All is fine so far. The last step is the actual comparison that displays the result in an image.

```
sudo docker exec -it opencv bash /face-recognition.sh
```

It gives the output:

```
[INFO] loading face detector...
[INFO] loading face recognizer...
No protocol specified
: cannot connect to X server :0
```

I have tried running the container with the following command:

```
sudo docker run -t -d --name opencv -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix opencv:latest
```

But it doesn't help.

Comment: Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks  like the xauth is the issue for viewing of the image. 
The details are at [Can you run GUI applications in a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296753/can-you-run-gui-applications-in-a-docker-container/25280523#25280523)

Answer (score 13):

Try running this,

```
xhost +

sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=host --ipc=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" <image_name> <arguments>
```

Other might face issue regarding the image not getting rendered on screen or getting a blank screen with no image, for them add `--env="_X11_NO_MITSHM=1"` to the above script while running the docker image. It will solve the problem.

For further information, I would recommend you guys check out the below references.

[Reference 1](https://marcosnietoblog.wordpress.com/2017/04/30/docker-image-with-opencv-with-x11-forwarding-for-gui/)
[Reference 2](http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI#Using_Wayland)

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `: cannot connect to X server /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zRvN9T3LeV/org.macosforge.xquartz:0`

Answer (score 2):

It may happen that also the `XAuthority` is needed.

First, make sure that the host's `$XAUTHORITY` is defined.
And second, add the following parameters to the `docker run` command:

```
-v $XAUTHORITY:/tmp/.XAuthority -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.XAuthority
```

An example of a complete command:

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti --net=host --ipc=host -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -v $XAUTHORITY:/tmp/.XAuthority -e XAUTHORITY=/tmp/.XAuthority --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" <image_name> <arguments>
```